# Any way to run glm() or similar function in R, when I only want to compute MLE estimate for coefficients of a logistic regression?

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, glm

Surprised I couldn't find any answer to this, or someone doing something similar.

Question: I am running a bootstraps on a GLM that takes a long time. However, I don't care about any output/SE's/tests or matrices that glm gives me, just the MLE for the coefficients (because I am using the bootstrap for uncertainty). It seems it would be way faster/memory efficient to just run the ML optimizer store MLE for each coefficient, rinse/repeat. Any way to do this besides writing an optim() script from scratch?

P.S. Q: Any way to tell glm() to use something besides IRWLS for algorithm, like N-R etc.

The X matrix is about 100mil observations, 10-15 parameters. I haven't had any serious issues with convergence, just a big matrix to deal with. I have been using fastglm(, method=3) which I found the fastest and to give answer comparable to glm().

It takes about 15-20 minutes to run the regression, so to get 200 or so bootstraps takes a few days. I would like to run in parallel but lack the memory for it.

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about the size/dimensions of your problem?

Comment: This is a slightly different use case from the linked duplicate (speeding up bootstrap replicates vs. speeding up a single large fit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should benchmark `glm.fit()`, which takes a model matrix `X` and a response `y` instead of doing all of the formula stuff. Also the `fastglm` package.

You might be able to speed `glm.fit` up a little bit by giving it the predicted values from the initial fit as `mustart` (this should cut the number of iterations required to converge).

`glm()` takes a `method=` argument; the default is `glm.fit` (IRLS), but you could swap in something else if you like. It's hard to know what you would want to substitute, though: at least for canonical link functions, IRLS is equivalent to N-R. Do you have a better/faster fitting algorithm in mind? "just run[ning] the ML optimize[r]": it will be pretty hard to improve on IRLS, I think.

---

Since you're already using `fastglm`, there's less scope for improvement. If one bootstrap replicate takes 15 minutes, then removing overhead (e.g. by using `fastglmPure` instead of `fastglm`, analogous to the difference between `glm.fit` and `glm`) will hardly do anything.  However, trying out different values of `method` (for faster but slightly less numerically stable algorithms) is probably worth a try ... (given that you're already using `method=3` I'm guessing you've tried that).

The only other performance tricks I can think of, in the absence of sufficient RAM/computing resources to run the bootstrap replicates in parallel, is to experiment with optimized/parallelized BLAS libraries. These should *not* in general require much additional memory, and [might speed up your linear algebra considerably](https://csantill.github.io/RPerformanceWBLAS/).

---

A little bit of benchmarking:

```r
library(fastglm)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(101)
n <- 1e6
dd <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n))
dd$y <- rbinom(n, size = 1, prob = plogis(2-3*dd$x))
X <- model.matrix(~x, data = dd)


b <- binomial()
m1 <- microbenchmark(
    glm = glm(y~x, dd, family = b),
    glm.fit = glm.fit(X, dd$y, family = b),
    fastglm = fastglm(X, dd$y, family = b),
    fpure = fastglmPure(X, dd$y, family = b),
    fpure3 = fastglmPure(X, dd$y, family = b, method = 3),
    times  = 20)

autoplot(m1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I actually am already using fastglm with initial values using a prior regression on the full sample. The procedure takes about an 15-20 mins as is. So to get enough bootstraps takes a couple days. I am not running in parallel because not enough memory...

Comment: Can you add these details to your question and give more other details of the computations?  (What are the dimensions of your `X` [number of observations and predictors]? How many bootstrap replicates are you running, how long does each take?) Can you get access to cloud computing resources?

Comment: oh wait: 15-20 minutes **per replicate** ??

Comment: Added some details to comment, I can't use cloud computing, but am looking into getting more RAM allocated for my server instance.

Comment: I would be interested to hear back whether using `fastpureGlm` with an alternative method buys you any significant speed.

Comment: As in your example, it is marginally faster but no major difference. One additional trick suggested to me was to stratify the data by subgroups (so they are smaller and can fit into RAM in parallel), this changes the estimator but not necessarily in a bad way.

Comment: Ben, I thought you might be interested. I tested out the parglm package, which breaks the QR decomposition into chunks and uses parallelized operations and it was much faster than the other options, probably because I have 32 cores to deploy. The other thing I haven't tried yet but thinking about is the "little bag of bootstraps" method, which may help speed up bootstrap procedure immensely. I am still looking into how it performs for longitudinal data / non i.i.d data.

Comment: For large GLMs I found that it's often beneficial to solve the weighted least squares step in the IRLS algo (https://bwlewis.github.io/GLM/) with the Eigen least squares conjugate gradient solver (callable using Rcpp & RcppEigen) - if your covariate matrix would happen to be sparse there is also a sparse LSCG eigen solver available too (fastglm for the moment does not support any of the eigen sparse solvers though, and least squares conjugate gradient is also not included for the dense case). I imagine that parglm could still be made a lot faster too by using LSCG instead of QR...

Comment: Or glmnet might be an option too? Just get your coefficients for lambda=0 if you are interested in the plain unregularised coefficients... Or the oem package, which works well for n >> p cases...

Comment: @TomWenseleers, feel free/I encourage you to write up an additional answer, even if it's short ...

Comment: @BenBolker Still cleaning up code of my L0glm package that I'ms working on. That one support all the dense & sparse Eigen solvers + osqp + glmnet as internal least squares solver. It uses an iterative adaptive ridge procedure to approximates the L0 penalty/best subset & uses a preset level of regularisation that approx. optimises AIC, BIC, GIC, MBIC or EBIC. A single IRLS iteration for a problem with n=p=10000 plus a ridge penalty would solve in 0.3s when parglm, speedglm, glm.fit & fastglm would take 9s, 20s, 208s & 237s & in 0.01s when X is sparse. https://github.com/Quantco/glum/issues/709

Comment: @BenBolker Once the code & documentation is cleaned up I'll put it public on my github & post a quick answer here!

Comment: @BenBolker Ha seems I can't add an answer as this question has been closed, but in addition to the options you give I tried speedglm.wfit, glmnet's bigGlm, oem and parglm.fit and parglm.fit was apparently the fastest using syntax parglm.fit = parglm.fit(X, dd$y, intercept = F, family = b, 
                      control = parglm.control(nthreads=8L, 
                             block_size=1000, 
                             method="FAST")).